# Change bootstrap nav element position on scroll (relative to page top)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with changing the position of an element using margin-top property.Element is inside bootstrap navigation end the problem is that it changes the margin on scroll properly,but whan I scroll page back to top,it doesnt change margin-top back to hire value.Here is my code:
JS

```js
$(".flags").css("margin-top", "24px");
 
        $(window).scroll(function(){

                var scrollingDiv = $(".flags").offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
                var menuMmainScroll = $(".navbar-nav>li>a").offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();

                if(menuMmainScroll === 68) {
                    $(".flags").css("margin-top", "24px");
                }

                else /**if(menuMmainScroll < 10)**/ {
                    $(".flags").css("margin-top", "10px");
                }
               



                console.log(menuMmainScroll);
               
                      
        });
```

```html
    <div class="menu_main">
        
      <div class="navbar yamm navbar-default">
        
          <div class="navbar-header">
            
            <div class="navbar-toggle .navbar-collapse .pull-right " data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1"  > <span>Menu</span>
              <button type="button" > <i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <div id="navbar-collapse-1" class="navbar-collapse collapse pull-right">
          
            <nav>
            
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              
               <li class="dropdown"><a href="index_new_fullmenu.html" class="dropdown-toggle active">Home</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="index_new_fullmenu.html">Forside</a></li>
              <li class="active"><a href="nytilyoga.html">Ny til Yoga</a></li>
              <li><a href="#holdplan" data-scroll>Holdplan</a></li>
              <li><a href="#priser" data-scroll>Priser</a></li>
              <li><a href="#kontakt" data-scroll>Kontakt</a></li>
              <li><a href="http://yogagear.dk/">Butik</a></li>
              <li><a href="http://memberservice.sport-solutions.dk/">Medlem log ind</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
              
                <li><a href="#holdplan" class="dropdown-toggle">Holdplan</a></li>
                <li><a href="#priser" class="dropdown-toggle">Priser</a></li>
                <li><a href="nytilyoga.html" class="dropdown-toggle">Ny til yoga</a></li>
                
                   <li class="dropdown"><a href="omyoga.html" class="dropdown-toggle">Om Yoga</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="mysore.html">Mysore metode</a></li>
                    <li><a href="omastanga">Om Astanga yoga</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                        
   <li><a href="mysore.html" class="dropdown-toggle">Mysore</a>  </li>
   <li><a href="studiet.html" class="dropdown-toggle">Studiet</a></li>
    <li><a href="studiet.html" class="dropdown-toggle">Butik</a></li>
 <li><div class="dropdown-toggle flags">  !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            <a href="#" class="flag-link"><img src="UK_flag.png" alt="English">
    </a>
            <a href="#" class="flag-link"><img src="DK_flag.png" alt="Danish">
    </a>
        </div>  !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!</li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
            </div>
          </div>
```

I have put `!`  at the beginning and end of troublesome part in HTML
Basicly in the beggining there is another menu on top of this one(whan page isnt scrolled,but whan the scrolling starts this menu takes over top position and stays fixed at the top.Now the problem is that I am using div with to images inside two links that are not display properly inline,but inline with some 24px above others in its own field,hoping this makes any sence.
thanks for any help guys.

Comment: unclear what you're asking. define "position". please re-write title to be more **specific**.

Comment: hope its clearer now :)

Comment: I've edited it to be clearer (I hope). good luck finding people which might help!

Comment: thanks! :) much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try editing the code in your scroll function to the below:

```
var menuMmainScroll = $(window).scrollTop();

if(menuMmainScroll === 0) {
    $(".flags").css("margin-top", "24px");
}
else {
    $(".flags").css("margin-top", "10px");
}
```

Comment: 68
22 0  this is my console.log.There is another menu which is 28px in height above this one whan page is at the top,and whan scrolling starts that menu stays up,and this one becomes fixed at the top of the page.My problem is that whan its scrolling down everything is ok,my script resolves the issue with the margin,but once I scroll back to the top of the page it doesnt return the margin-top to 24px but instead keeps it at 10px(whan the other menu is shgowed once again and this 1 is below him)

Comment: yes...tryed a lot of other logic choices,but somehow whatever i do it wont change whan you scroll it back all the way to the top

Comment: I'm not sure what your console.log output is when you hit the top of the page, but I edited my post with code that should work.

Comment: Just seen what you did there,it works great!My fault that I wosnt reading just took a look and thought I already did that...Thanks a lot one more time,much appreciated ! :-)